# Create Android java notification for Flutter package and redirect to the app when clicked

Tags: java, flutter

I'm creating a flutter package. I am creating a notification in the Android java section, but when I click on this notification, I want to go to the application, but I can't figure out how to do it.

My notification generation code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .setVisibility(publicVersion ? NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
                        : NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

builder.setContentTitle(getString(s));
return builder.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pending intent : https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#java

```
// Create an Intent for the activity you want to start
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
// Create the TaskStackBuilder and add the intent, which inflates the back stack
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
// Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE); NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I know this. I don't know how can I do this for flutter package?